# 404 Error Related to Slider Revolution Plugin in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/concretep1/public_html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/page-template.class.php on line 115
Did try to disable that plugins but still error is there.

```
global $post;

    if (!isset($this->templates[get_post_meta( 
        $post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true 
    )] ) ) {

        return $template;
```

Comment: What is `$this`? Without context the code you posted makes no sense...

Comment: Do you have FTP access

Comment: the error says it's on this line ' $post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true ' I've tried to test it on localhost seems working fine. Sorry can't give ftp I only have wp access.